# How to get Google search results displayed on a website using php?

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to get Googles search results displayed on my webpage, but I'm failing with some examples that I've found in the Google Docs. Here is what I've so far - this does not display any result. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$query = 'test';
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&key=myKeyfromAPI&q=".$query;

$body = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($body);

for($x=0;$x<count($json->responseData->results);$x++){
echo "<b>Result ".($x+1)."</b>";
echo "<br>URL: ";
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->url;
echo "<br>VisibleURL: ";
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->visibleUrl;
echo "<br>Title: ";
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->title;
echo "<br>Content: ";
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->content;
echo "<br><br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to register your own project to get The API Key.

You can register from the following link:

https://developers.google.com/

After you registered your own project activate Custom Search API then take your api key and add it here:

$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&key=**myKeyfromAPI**&q=".$query;

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "mykeyfromApi" is just a placeholder, I've my APIkey inserted for testing without any results. ie. $body is empty.

Comment: Did you tried to activate Custom Search from project apis at google developers?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. Do I have to load any .js files or something else or is this running without any additionally scripts and just with the API-key?

Comment: Hello Can some tell me on how to increase the results limit ? it is just returning 4 search results !